# Prove that $\{T_v: \|v\|\leq 1\}$ is a family of pointwise uniformly bounded functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

> Let $V,W$ be Hilbert spaces and $A:V\rightarrow W$, $B:W^*\rightarrow V^*$ linear operators such that $l(Av)=(Bl)(v)$ for all $v\in V$ and for all $l\in W^*$.
> For $v\in V$ define $T_v(l):=l(A(v))$ for all $l\in W^*$. Then I need to show that for all $l\in W^*$ $$\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}|T_v(l)|<\infty$$

I wanted to do it as follows:
$$\begin{align}\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}|T_v(l)|&=\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}|l(A(v))|\\&\leq\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}\|l\|~\|A\|~\|v\|\\&\leq \|l\|~\|A\|\end{align}$$Now since $l\in W^*$ I know that $\|l\|<\infty$. But I don't know anything about $A$. I only know that $\|A\|=\|B\|$,i.e. if $A$ is bounded then $B$ is bounded but I don't see how this helps me.

Can maybe someone help me how to conclude?

Comment: Use `\|` instead of `||` to get proper double norm bars.

Comment: @joriki done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|T_v(l)|=|l(A(v))|=|(B(l))(v)|\le\|B(l)\|\|v\|.$$

Comment: Sorry I don't see for what this computation should be useful? I mean I see how it goes but at the end I would get $\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}|T_v(l)|\leq \|B(l)\|$

Comment: Exactly! So I proved that this sup is finite. This is what you asked. When you say "I would get" do you mean: "I understand I get" or "I don't understand why" ?

Comment: So I understand why I then get $\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}|T_v(l)|\leq \|B(l)\|$ but I don't see why I get finiteness because $\|B(l)\|\leq \|B\|~\|l\|$ and we are at the same point as in my computation but with $B$ instead of $A$

Comment: I don't say $\|B(l)\|\leq \|B\|~\|l\|.$ I use directly that $\|B(l)\|<\infty$ because $B(l)\in V^*,$ because your $*$ means topological dual since you said "since $l∈W^∗$
 I know that $∥l∥<∞$".

Comment: No problem so see you in 3 hours.

Comment: Question for later:\\

Ah so there is the point. But I cannot say it in my computation above so I could say that $\sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}|l(A(v))|\leq \sup_{\|v\|\leq 1}| \|l(A)\| ~\|v\|\leq \|l(A)\|$ right? but this does not help me since this is something in $\Bbb{K}$?

Comment: $l(A(v))\ne(l(A))(v)$ because $l(A)$ does not even exist. $A\in L(V,W),l\in W^*.$ It is $l\circ A$ which exist, bu you have no direct control on its norm since you don't know yet that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Ah I see thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution is certainly better and cleaner than the mine. The solution I gave above was intended to continue your idea of bounding $\Vert l \Vert \Vert A \Vert$. However, what @AnneBauval wrote is a really faster way to conclude that $\sup_{\Vert v \Vert \leq 1} \vert T_v(l)\vert$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

What you are computing is the norm of $lA = l \circ A \in V^*$. Indeed
$$
\sup_{\|v \| \leq 1} | T_v(l) | = \sup_{\|v \| \leq 1} | l (A(v)) |\sup_{\|v \| \leq 1} | (l \circ A)v | = \| l \circ A \|_{V^*}.
$$
Now the last number is finite for any $l \in W^*$ if and only if $A : V \rightarrow W$ is bounded. Indeed if $A$ is bounded then $l \circ A$ is also bounded. Conversly if all the $(l \circ A)_{l \in W^*}$ are bounded, you then know that $A$ is continuous from $V$ endowed of the norm topology to $W$ endowed of its weak topology. This is enough to say that $A$ is continuous, indeed then the graph of $A$ is strongly closed and by the closed graph theorem $A$ is strongly continuous.

So I think your problem miss the hypothesis "$A$ bounded".

**Added** : After the explanations of Anne Beauval I realized that to *define* the adjoint (what you call $B$) as a map $A^* : W^* \rightarrow V^*$ you **need** to require $A$ continuous. Indeed you trapped yourself saying that $V^*$ and $W^*$ stand for the topological dual spaces, hence continuous mappings. Then using what I showed you above you get
$$
\begin{align}
A^* \text{ well defined} &\Longrightarrow \left[ \forall w^* \in W^*,\quad A^*w^* \in V^* \right]\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left[ \forall w^* \in W^*,\quad w^* \circ A \in V^* \right]\\
&\Longleftrightarrow A \text{ continuous}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: But if I would have $A$ bounded I can simply continue my argument and say that $\|l\| ~\|A\|<\infty$ right?

Comment: But it seems a bit strange to me because the next part of the exercise tells me to show that $A$ and $B$ are bounded. This part would not make any sense if in the hypothesis $A$ is bounded. Thus I think it is not missing.

Comment: Yes, if you know that $A$ is bounded then what you did in your question shows that the supremum you are computing is finite. What I am showing is that $conversly$ if these suprema are finite for any $l$, then necessarily $A$ is bounded. If your exercise makes you show that $A$ is bounded without any further hypothesis then it is obviously false: it would make you show that any merely linear map $V \rightarrow W$ is continuous. This happens if and only if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @user1294729 I edited my answer proving you that you **need** to ask $A$ continuous in order for $B$ to be well defined.

Comment: @blamethelag I think we actually don't need to ask $A$ continuous in the set up given in the question. If $V$ and $W$ are Banach spaces and $A:V\to W$ and $B: W^*\to V^*$ are functions satisfying $l(Av)=(Bl)(v)$ for all $v \in V$ and $l \in W^*$, then we gain automatically that $A$ and $B$ are linear and continuous (we could even drop the linearity of the assumptions if we want). See my answer below.

Comment: @lfsm your proof is a paraphrase of what I wrote. Moreover you did not get the point of what I taught you: when you consider $B$ as a map taking values in $W^*$ you are assuming that $A$ is bounded. This is why I claim the exercise is poorly phrased.

Comment: The exercise is not poorly phrased. Why do we need $A:V\to W$ bounded to define $B:W^* \to V^*$ satisfying $l(Av) = (Bl)(v)$ for all $l \in W^*$? This is just saying that if you have a functional linear $l$ in $W^*$, then applying $l$ to an element $Av$ of the image of $A$ is the same as applying the image of $l$ under $B$ to $v$. Why this is not well defined? We don't need even to ask $A$ and $B$ to be linear. My proof is not a paraphrase of what you wrote. I didn't claim that $B$ is not well defined. I proved that $A$ is continuous without assuming nothing else than what is given in the qst.

Comment: In the given set up, we can actually prove that $A$ and $B$ are continuous and linear. We don't need to ask them to be continuous and linear (this is a consequence). Moreover, he didn't say in any moment that $B$ is the adjoint of $A$. In fact, we are proving that in this case $B$ has to be the adjoint of $A$, but this is not an assumption as you said in your answer. This is a consequence.

Comment: @lfsm please read again my comment. There I prove that **if** $B$ is well defined, **then** $A$ is continuous. Also you can prove that **if** $B$ is well defined, **then** $A$ is linear. It means that saying "let $A$ and $B$ defined by your equation" is **not** correct because it is not trivial that for any $A:V \rightarrow W$ such a $B$ exists and is well defined. Indeed, I taught you that $B$ is well defined if and only if $A$ was linear continuous. Therefore saying "let" is not correct, what should be said is "suppose we can define $B$ as ...".

Comment: @lfsm "I did not use that $B$ is well defined" ... well you used it as a valid mathematical object, which means you are assuming it is well defined. Note that you even used that it was well defined as a map $W^* \rightarrow V^*$ (!) Recall: you **cannot** use an object which is not well defined/does not exist. I leave you as an exercise that: if you can use a not well defined object, then you can prove everything.

Comment: @lfsm Please read again your answer and mine: you used the closedness of the graph to get continuity and a duality argument to get strong closedness of the graph. This is exactly how I have done.

Comment: (1) There is no problem in assuming the existence of such $B$ (please note: we are \textbf{assuming} it). What we are proving in the exercise is: if such a $B$ exists and is well defined, then $A$ is continuous. We do not need to require $A$ continuous to suppose that such a $B$ exists (again note: we are \textbf{supposing} the existence). This is just an assumption and we are proving that, with this assumption, $A$ has to be continuous. When you say that the exercise is missing the hypothesis that $A$ is continuous, you are not right. The exercise is missing nothing.

Comment: (2) You are paraphrasing something that I didn't write... Where did I write "I did not use that $B$ is well defined"??. It seems that **you** are not reading what I'm writing. What I wrote was: "I didn't claim that B is not well defined". And I said this to make clear: my answer is completely different from yours since you are claiming that the exercise is not missing something. I didn't claim that the exercise is poorly phrased (and it is not), I just solved it.

Comment: Correcting a phrase from previous comment: "...since you are claiming that the exercise *is* missing somethin..."

Comment: (3) "Recall: you cannot use an object which is not well defined/does not exist". This is obvious. I will repeat once more: we are **assuming** the existence of such a $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Both $A$ and $B$ are bounded (it seems this is what you need to finish your argument).

Firstly, let us see the boundedness of $A$. Since $V$ and $W$ are Banach spaces and $A$ is already linear, by the Closed Graph Theorem, it suffices to prove that $$v_n \to v, \ Av_n \to w \Rightarrow Av = w.$$ In fact, assuming the left hand side above, we have for $l \in W^*$: $$l(w) = l\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} Av_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}l(Av_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (Bl)(v_n) = (Bl)(v) = l(Av).$$ Since this is true for all $l \in W^*$, the Hahn-Banach Theorem implies $Av=w$ as desired. This proves the boundedness of $A$.

The boundedness of $B$ now follows trivially from $$\vert Bl(v) \vert = \vert l(Av)\vert \leq \Vert y'\Vert\Vert A\Vert\Vert x \Vert.$$

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: 1) In his comment to blamethelag's answer, user1294729 wrote "the next part of the exercise tells me to show that A and B are bounded". But this is not what he is asking here. 2) Where does "$\lim_{n\to\infty} (Bl)(v_n) = (Bl)(v) $" come from?

Comment: 1) In the end of his question, he presented an idea and his idea could be finished if we had boundedness of $A$. I presented a proof that $A$ is bounded. It is directly related with his question.

2) $Bl$ belongs to $W^*$ and hence it is continuous. The continuity of $Bl$ yields $\lim_{n\to\infty} (Bl)(v_n) = (Bl)(v)$

Comment: (Added before getting your answer above about 2)): I retract my question 2), I simply missed that your $Bl$ meant $B(l),$ and that this continuity of $B(l)$ was exactly my answer.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the notation given in the question.

Comment: Sorry to disturb again. But to prove that $A$ is bounded can't I use the principle of uniform boundedness?

Comment: @user1294729 Maybe. How would you use it?

Comment: I would use it on $\{T_v: ||v||\leq 1\}$

Comment: @user1294729 Ok, and how would this imply a bound for A?

Comment: Ah it does not imply a bound on $A$ right?

Comment: I would not say this does not imply, but I couldn't see it so easily. Do you have an argument using the Uniform Boundedness Principle?